# How to update someone else's changes done in my local branch?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch, pull-request, branching-and-merging

After sending a Pull Request with changes on my local branch (`branch1`), someone else pushed some more changes into my own branch (`branch1`).

How do I update my own branch with those changes?

Comment: To where did you send this Pull Request? (GitHub, Bitbucket, GitLab, ...?)

Comment: @torek I send it to GitHub. 

Eventually I found out that in order to update changes done on the same local branch on GitHub you gotta type this command line to have it rebased 

`git pull origin (branch_name) --rebase`